# Having trouble with this exercise

Tags: ruby

I am working on *Head First Ruby*. Here is my code:

```
class Employee
  attr_reader :name

  def name=(name)
  end

  def print_name
    puts "Name: #{name}"
  end
end

class SalariedEmployee < Employee
  attr_reader :salary

  def salary=(salary)
    # code to validate and set @salary
  end

  def print_pay_stub
    print_name
    pay_for_period = (salary / 365.0) * 14
    formatted_pay = format("$%.2f", pay_for_period)
    puts "Pay this period: #{formatted_pay}"
  end
end

class HourlyEmployee < Employee
  attr_reader :hourly_wage, :hours_per_week

  def hourly_wage=(hourly_wage)
    # code to validate and set @hourly_wage
  end

  def hours_per_week=(hours_per_week)
    # code to validate and set @hours_per_week
  end

  def print_pay_stub
    print_name
    pay_for_period = hourly_wage * hours_per_week * 2
    formatted_pay = format("$%.2f", pay_for_period)
    puts "pay This Period: #{formatted_pay}"
  end
end
```

I cannot get this exercise to work. I get this error:

```
employee.rb:42:in `print_pay_stub': undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from employee.rb:56:in `<main>'
```

Could someone look over this code and tell what is going wrong?

Comment: which line is line 42?

Comment: pay_for_period = hourly_wage * hours_per_week * 2

Comment: Hint: in that empty method that doesn't do anything which only has the comment "code to validate and set `@hourly_wage`" in it, there should be code to validate and set `@hourly_wage` in it.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that a little bit ago. I did not realize that is was telling me to add something. Bah. Been working on this since the early hours of the morning. I think I need to step away from the computer for a while =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: My mistake -- either `hourly_wage` or `hours_per_week` is nil. Make sure those are set.

<strike>It looks like `salary` is `nil` -- at least, that's the only line there with an `*`. You need to make sure `salary` is set</strike>

Edit: clarification

Edit 2: correction

Comment: I was not trying to access the part of Salary. I am trying to do the Hourly part. That is why salary is nil. The error os on line 42 and 56.  pay_for_period = hourly_wage * hours_per_week * 2

Comment: Gotcha. So you need to make sure hourly_wage and hours_per_week are set.

Comment: I did set those. You can see it better in the gist. https://gist.github.com/jeffwolfram/cb72b4301feaf1adb55c7888ec2b3c6f

Comment: In the code you're actually running, did you write the `hourly_wage=` and `hours_per_week=` methods? Without those, the attributes won't actually be set.

Comment: `   hourly_employee = HourlyEmployee.new
hourly_employee.name = "Amy"
hourly_employee.hourly_wage = 14
hourly_employee.hours_per_week = 30
hourly_employee.print_pay_stub       `

Comment: No, I see where you're *calling* the methods. But you need to *define* them. As in `def hourly_wage=(wage) @hourly_wage = wage end`

Comment: sorry for some reason I can not figure out how to make it show up as code

Comment: No worries. Sorry about the formatting on the method code -- I can make a gist (or comment on yours) if that makes it more clear.

Comment: You have helped me a lot. I think I know where my mistake is. I am going to try it now.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.